# Jooq (PostgreSQL) - condition build from list of substrings, case-insensitive

Tags: kotlin, conditional-statements, jooq, ignore-case

I'm looking for a efficient way to find items in a table (lets say Location) with a column "short_name". In my Kotlin code I have a couple of filter queries and in two of them a property with a list of approx 1000 names as substrings, so I need to look for substrings and it should be case-insensitive.

I found a couple solutions, but all of them take a lot of time.

Data model: `filter.shortNames: List<String>? = null`

Solution 1 - "fold":

```
filter.shortNames?. let {
    val first = it.first()
    condition = condition.and(
        it.minus(first).fold(LOCATION.SHORTNAME.likeIgnoreCase("%$first%")) { con: Condition, name: String ->
            con.or(LOCATION.KEY.likeIgnoreCase("%$name%"))
        }
    )
}
```

Solution 2 - "like any":

```
filter.shortNames?. let {
    condition = condition.and(DSL.lower(LOCATION.SHORTNAME).like(DSL.any(*it.map { e -> "%${e.lowercase()}%" }.toTypedArray())))
}
```

Like I said, the requests with both solutions take around 7 sec for all filter-queries. And the pain is definitely the condition with the short_name.

I couldn't find a better solution, which reduces the response time significantly. So I hope for help here.

Thank you guys.

Comment: I would try [text search](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-textsearch.html) instead of `LIKE` predicates